# Bash condition for scheduled event

Tags: bash

Tryng to get this script working, to schedule an event inside a while cycle that check if is the right moment or not to do something.

like: if week's day is equal and hours is major do it, else don't do it, but if week's day and hour are equal check also for minutes equal or major..

The input txt file, an example of the schedule date:

```
2
23
45
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#CHECKTIME


#GET TIME
#Corrected by chepner

IFS=- read -r DAY HOUR MINUTE < <(date +%e-%H-%M)
echo $DAY
echo $HOUR
echo $MINUTE


#READ EVENT TIME
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < myFile.txt
echo $line[0]
echo $line[1]
echo $line[2]


if [ "$DAY" =  "$line[0]" ] && [ "$HOUR" -ge  "$line[1]"]  && [ "$MINUTE" > "$line[2]"]
then
    echo "do event "

else
        echo "don't do event"
#echo $name
fi
```

Comment: `line` is not an array; it's a single string. You probably want something like `IFS= read -r d h m` to split a line into day, hour, and minute fields. Also, if `myFile.txt` only has one line, you can simply use `IFS= read -r m d h < myFile.txt`. Right now, you are reading each line, but only using the *last* line to compare to `DAY`, `HOUR`, and `MINUTE`.

Comment: Also, don't call `date` three times (there is a minor race condition, where it's possible that the first `date` gets called *just* before midnight, and the second one gets called *just* after. Use something like `IFS=- read -r DAY HOUR MINUTE < <(date +%e-%H-%M)`.

Comment: Thanks! myFile.txt has one value each line, in order week's day, hour and minutes

Comment: im unable to use IFS= read -r d h m < myFile.txt with echo only the first value is displayed

Comment: I'm only guessing at how to parse the line, since you haven't shown the input. It's also not clear how you plan to use *each* line; you probably need more code in the `while` loop rather than *after* the loop.

Comment: thanks for suggestions, @chepner I add the input to my question, 3 variables, one per line.

Comment: While unrelated to the *ask*, `cron` might be highly related to the actual *goal* and should be worth researching / considering for this

Comment: On other unrelated note, other then `cron` use `systemd.timer` or  `atd` to schedule a script to execute later. There is no question in your post, in the spirit of this forum, would be nice to ask a question.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, in my case i have this txt with day hour and minute in each line, writed by php form, when an event already running for undefined time end, then the script have to compare thats variables and determinate if do something or not, during the main event i can't check to compare thats values, only when it end,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each input is on a single line, you need to save each line separately. `read -r line` doesn't append to an array named `line` each time it is called.

```
{
   IFS= read -r DAY
   IFS= read -r HOUR
   IFS= read -r MINUTE
} < myFile.txt
```